# How to move a path point over time

Tags: animation, path

My model includes a path (representing an arm of a little stick-man) with three points.  I want two of these points to remain fixed, and the third (the "hand") to move with time, as if he is waving.

I imagined I would be able to insert keyframes for the path's third point, but that doesn't seem to be possible.

Is there a way to move only one point in a path (i.e. change the path) with time?

Alternatively, is there another way I can achieve the effect please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can do this easily by going into edit mode, selecting the vertex you want to animate, and pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> *> Hook to New Object*. You can now animate the new *Empty* and that vertice will follow it's position exactly.

[image: Vertex Hook]